# getting text box entry data from Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a TKinter to make a interface that will take in user name, password, a web link.

I am having problems getting the entry box variable to enter into my global variable.
I get NameError: name 'userEntry' is not defined

I have tried calling self. and init_window and append.But I am really fumbling in the dark, this is the first time I have used the class Window(Frame) for tkinter, so i am not exactly sure what I am screwing up.

----------------------Edit----------------------------------------------------------

I want to take the text data from `init_window(self)` and use the data in `runProgram(self)` as an variable for selenium. But i cant get the data to transfer over.

```
data = []
userName= []
password=[]
link=[]

class Window(Frame):

     def __init__(self, master=None):
         Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
         self.master = master
         self.init_window()

    #Creation of init_window
     def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("Comment uploader") # changing the title of our master widget         

        userEntry= Entry(root, textvariable=userName)
        passEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=password, show='*')
        linkEntry= Entry(root, textvariable=link)
        openButton = Button(root, text="Open CSV", command=self.fileOpen) # creating a button instance
        goButton = Button(root, text="Run program", command=self.runProgram)

        userEntry.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky=W)
        passEntry.grid(row=1, column=2,sticky=W)
        linkEntry.grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=W) 
        openButton.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)  
        goButton.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

        label_1= Label(root,text="User Name:" ,font="Times 14")
        label_2= Label(root,text="Password:" ,font="Times 14")
        label_3= Label(root,text="input link" ,font="Times 14")
        label_4= Label(root,text="Open CSV" ,font="Times 14")
        label_5= Label(root,text="Sart the program" ,font="Times 14")

        label_1.grid(row=0 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_2.grid(row=1 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_3.grid(row=2 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_4.grid(row=3 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_5.grid(row=4 , column=1, sticky=W) 

     def runProgram(self):
          userName = userEntry.get()

          print(userName)
          print(data[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a variable in a function in which it is not created you should make the variable an instance variable:

```
self.userEntry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=userName)
```

This applies to all objects that are shared within the class. For instance; you don't need to share the entry `userEntry` as you have a textvariable associated with the entry, but you'll have to share the textvariable.

Here is a rewrite of the program with instance variables used how I think you are aiming for:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
        self.master = master
        self.data = []
        self.userName = StringVar() # StringVar to hold userEntry content
        self.password = StringVar() # etc, etc.
        self.link = StringVar()
        self.init_window()          # Build GUI

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Comment uploader") # changing the title of our master widget         

        userEntry= Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.userName)
        passEntry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.password, show='*')
        linkEntry= Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.link)
        openButton = Button(self.master, text="Open CSV", command=self.fileOpen) # creating a button instance
        goButton = Button(self.master, text="Run program", command=self.runProgram)

        userEntry.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky=W)
        passEntry.grid(row=1, column=2,sticky=W)
        linkEntry.grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=W) 
        openButton.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)  
        goButton.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

        label_1= Label(root,text="User Name:" ,font="Times 14")
        label_2= Label(root,text="Password:" ,font="Times 14")
        label_3= Label(root,text="input link" ,font="Times 14")
        label_4= Label(root,text="Open CSV" ,font="Times 14")
        label_5= Label(root,text="Sart the program" ,font="Times 14")

        label_1.grid(row=0 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_2.grid(row=1 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_3.grid(row=2 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_4.grid(row=3 , column=1, sticky=W)
        label_5.grid(row=4 , column=1, sticky=W)

    def fileOpen(self): # Placeholder for button callback
        pass

    def runProgram(self):
        userName = self.userName.get()
        print(userName)
        #print(self.data[1])    # The list self.data is empty...

root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```